# SELECT Query in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an ms access table like the following:

```
UserName | PC_Type
Rob      | Desktop
Frank    | Laptop
Rob      | Laptop
Lindesy  | ThinCient
Mark     | Desktop
Paul     | Desktop
Paul     | ThinClient
```

How can I create a SELECT query that returns only users who doesn't have neither ThinClient nor Laptop?

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserName, PC_Type 
From Table 
GROUP BY UserName, PC_Type
HAVING PC_Type <> "ThinClient" AND PC_Type <> "Laptop"  
[or where PC_Type Not In ("ThinClient", "Laptop")]
```

but this doesn't filter users excluding who has already a Laptop (or ThinClient) because it returns for instance "ROB | Desktop" who has already a laptop (or "Paul | Desktop" who has already a ThinClient).
I tried queries to find duplicates, difference queries, crossqueries, but I'm starting to get confused.
I was trying to create a subquery or a partition query but I don't know if I'm doing something right.

Anyone can help me with this, please ?
I'd expect from the query to return only Mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT UserName
From Table 
GROUP BY UserName
HAVING SUM(IIF(PC_Type IN ("ThinClient", "Laptop"), 1, 0) = 0 ;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, for your prompt reply ! That's the correct query, I've just played around it because initially it gave me type mismatch as I put HAVING condition in the criteria of PC_Type field, while it should be added in a separate "expression" field.

Comment: The amended query is this:

`SELECT [Table].UserName
FROM [Table] 
GROUP BY [Table].UserName
HAVING (((Sum(IIf([Table]!PC_Type In ("ThinClient","Laptop"),1,0)))=0));`

Thanks !